# iOS UILabel size issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I searched for 4 hours before writing my question, none of the answers I saw online solve this issue.

I'm working on an iOS app, and in the storyboard, when I'm using a UILabel, no matter what I do, there's always extra padding on top, this is causing me a big issue since I'm trying to have a pixel perfect design.

I still don't understand where this is coming from, I tried using Plain text, and I tried attributed strings, both still give this extra padding:

Screenshot: 
[http://imgur.com/Fldcodl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AHMW.jpg)

I tried to subclass the label with the following:

```
var textInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero {
    didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
}


override var bounds:CGRect {
    get {
        return super.bounds
    }
    set {
        super.bounds = newValue
        if (self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != super.bounds.size.width) {
            self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = super.bounds.size.width;
            self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        }

    }
}

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
    let insetRect = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, textInsets)
    let textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: insetRect, limitedToNumberOfLines: numberOfLines)
    let invertedInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: -textInsets.top,
                                      left: -textInsets.left,
                                      bottom: -textInsets.bottom,
                                      right: -textInsets.right)
    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(textRect, invertedInsets)
}

override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, textInsets))
}
```

Even with the values for top left right bottom set to 0 I still get this annoying top padding.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried sizeToFit?

Comment: What is it that you don't like? I don't see any "top padding".

Comment: @danh yes it didn't work

Comment: @matt there's 4 points above the actual text within the yellow background :) the yellow background is the UILabel background that I added for you guys to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: A label provides some leading space. This is normal. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: I know it adds leading space, that's why I'm asking the question :) 
It's not needed, I'm trying to have a pixel perfect design implementation.

Comment: You are talking about little yellow space around the text or the white space around yellow area? Are you using custom fonts?

Comment: There is probably the yellow padding owing to the label fitting the font inside it. If you see closely there is very little gap between "y" and the label border. I don't think the padding will get smaller than that!

Comment: `font.lineHeight` and `label.bounds.height` is the same after I print it out. I think its the underlying problem of text drawing in iOS then `UILabel`.

Comment: @Mr.Bista I'm talking about the yellow area, and no I'm not using any custom font this is the system font. 
If you change UIEdgeInsets top value to any negative value you start seeing it shrinking, but this is not a solution of course cause this area increases and decreases depending on font size. 

It's a very weird behavior

Comment: @Rikh 4 pixels is not a very little gap, that's actually a lot, it breaks your vertical alignment totally

Comment: That is 4 pixels between the bottom part of "y" and label border?

Comment: @Rikh yup, 2 pixels on retina screen = 4 pixels :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are wanting to remove the white space around your label (not entirely clear from your question).

Your label has a yellow background, the margin you're trying to remove is outside the label, so no amount of subclassing will remove it.

The way you add the label to the screen (in code or Interface Builder, via constraints or frames) is what defines those margins, that is the what you need to adjust to fix your margins.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added the yellow background so that you guys can see what I'm talking about, it's not the white space, the white space is the view, my issue is with the extra space above the text that is in the yellow.
The yellow is the background of the Label, this is not needed, I want the top to stop right on the edge of the text without those extra 4 points

Comment: I changed the picture, now it's clearer which space I'm talking about I guess